# How to use MONTHNAME in a MySQL query to match months

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm building a query so I can get a list of new users by month:

```
public function getNewUsers($month) {

        $month = date('F', strtotime($month));

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `{$this->table}` WHERE MONTHNAME(`account_creation_date`) = {$month} ORDER BY `id` DESC";
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([$month]);

        if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0) return null;

        $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NAMED);

        foreach ($users as &$user) {

            $user = $this->applyRelations($user);

        }

        return $users;

    }
```

An example of "account_creation_date" value is "08/08/2019 4:55 pm"

Im trying to pass in a month name like "August" and have the query convert the account_creation_date values to their month names.

Although I'm getting no errors, nothing is returning when the query is executed.

How can I accomplish this? Is MONTHNAME what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: test this see what is returned `SELECT *, MONTHNAME(account_creation_date) FROM {$this->table} `

Comment: What is in the `$month` variable that is passed into the function?

Comment: @tim it's making the column name MONTHNAME(account_creationg_date) with all the values for that column showing as null

Comment: @Nick in this case $month = "August"

Comment: So why bother with `date('F", strtotime($month))`? if the value is already "August"?

Comment: @Nick it's for the case that it's not passed in like that but something similar that can be converted

Comment: Your problem is that your execute will fail because you are passing a parameter but you have no parameters in the query. Change the query to `$sql = "SELECT * FROM \`{$this->table}\` WHERE MONTHNAME(\`account_creation_date\`) = ? ORDER BY \`id\` DESC";`

Comment: if null are you sure account_creation_date exists? is a date field?

Comment: @tim it's a varchar (I know thats not the best for dates in mysql)

Comment: thats a problem, it has to be a date to use `MONTHNAME()` on it

Comment: ah ok thanks. back to the drawing board then

Comment: Why are you using `MONTHNAME` instead of `MONTH`? Numbers are generally easier to work with than strings.

Comment: @tim It doesn't have to be a date. If it's a string it will be converted to a date first.

Comment: You should be getting errors. First, you didn't put quotes around `{$month}`, so it should complain about the unknown column `August`. Second, you're passing an array of parameters to `execute()`, but don't have any placeholders in the query.

Comment: Are you sure you have `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` enabled in your PDO settings, so that you get notified of the errors?

Comment: @Barmar are you sure? OP gets null, i get null when tested: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/913d64/1

Comment: It works if the string is formatted in a way that MySQL can parse it. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/964fc5/1

Comment: fair enough, but that's not the format the OP has. so still has to either change format or type to be able to use MONTHNAME(`account_creation_date`)

Comment: if you creation date is a datetime or timestamp you wouldn't have any problems in the first place, `MONTHNAME` should have worked fine, now you have to parse the actual date first with `STR_TO_DATE` mumbo jumbo then use `MONTHNAME`, now more loops to get there